# Error correction : He feels his troubles as much or even more than they

Tags: exam-questions, error

> He feels his troubles as much or even more than they.

This is an error spotting question asked in my exam, I am particularly stuck at two spots in the sentence . First if its correct to use *as much* here or its better to use *as much as.* I looked up for the phrase in Merriam Webster [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/much) but could find only one sentence which has used *as much* in it and I am not able to make out from that whether to use *as much* here or *as much as*. Second, Is the *they* used correct or should it be replaced with *them* ? What I have learned is that nominative cases are compared with nominative and objective cases with objective, so accordingly *they* is correct with *he* but somebody on a three year old yahoo answers thread had suggested correction with *them*.

Comment: If that's an "exam" question, it's a rubbish exam. In theory your example is a shorter version of *...as much **as** or even more than they **do*** (where the highlighted words have been "deleted". But those deletions don't represent "mistakes" - they're just features of normal English usage. IMHO replacing ***they*** with ***them*** is also just a stylistic choice, but I suppose it's feasible some pedant might object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*as much or even more than* is OK, but your example should read:

> He feels his troubles as much or even more than **they do**.

In this way, it is clear that nominative case is correct.